# SQL Server 2012 - updating a column based on row to row comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare, sql-server-2012, rows

I have a table that contains dates and times. For example columns are `Date`, `ExTime`, `NewTime`, `Status`. I am ordering them based on a `expkey` column that makes them show in the right order.

I want to do a row by row comparison and compare the second row column of `extime` to the first row column `NewTime`. If extime < Newtime then I want to update `status` with a "1". And then traverse through the table row by row where second row in the above example becomes the first and a new second is pull and used. Here is a sample of what I have now - but it is not hitting and working all all of the rows for some reason.

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Status = 1
FROM MyTable t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 NewTime
             FROM MyTable
             WHERE ID = t.ID AND [Date] = t.[Date]
             ORDER BY ExpKey) t1
WHERE t.Extime < t1.NewTime
```

This is not hitting all the rows like I want it to. I have the where clause comparing fields ID and Date to insure that the rows are attached to the same person. If the ID or Dates are not the same it is not attached to the same person so I would not want to update the status. So basically if the ID of Row 2 = ID of Row 1 and Date of Row 2 = Date of Row 1 I want to compare extime of row 2 and see if it is less than newtime of Row 1 - if so then update the status field of row 2.

Any help in figuring out why this sort of works but not on all would be appreciated.

Ad.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in pure SQL.  You'll need some sort of program to do this.

Comment: @Andrew if I understand problem correctly, this is possible with lag function in SQL 2012 or more clumsy solutions with apply or row_number in SQL server 2008

Answer (score 4):

On SQL Server 2012 you can easily update `status` with window function [`lag()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx):

```
with cte as (
    select
        extime,
        lag(newtime) over(partition by id, date order by expKey) as newtime,
        status
    from table1
)
update cte set status = 1 where extime < newtime;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dbc08/1)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I've dealt with similar issues of comparing adjacent rows. I put this together off-the-cuff, so it may need tweaking, but give it a try.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT ID,[Date],ExpKey,ExTime,NewTime,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID,[Date] ORDER BY ExpKey) AS Sort
    FROM MyTable
)
UPDATE row2
SET row2.[Status] = 2
WHERE row2.ExTime < row1.NewTime
FROM CTE row2
CROSS JOIN CTE row1
    ON row1.ID = row2.ID
    AND row1.[Date] = row2.[Date]
    AND row1.Sort = row2.Sort-1 --Join to prior row
```